# Simple Redirection in C

Tags: c, osx-mountain-lion, io-redirection

I am a beginner just learning the basics of C in Xcode 5 in OSX. I received an assignment in the course I am doing to redirect information (the values relevant to the program) from an input file (input.txt) into a simple program and then to display the results in a second file (output.txt).

Here is a copy of the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NIS_PER_LITER 5.37

int main()
{

    double speed, hrs, km_per_liter;
    double liters, cost;

    printf("Enter driving time in hrs: ");
    scanf("%lf", &hrs);
    printf("Enter driving speed in kph: ");
    scanf("%lf", &speed);
    printf("Enter km per liter: ");
    scanf("%lf", &km_per_liter);

    liters = hrs * speed / km_per_liter;
    cost = liters * NIS_PER_LITER;

    printf("Your driving cost is %lf NIS\n", cost);

    return 0;
}
```

I have already tried using: `command < input.txt > output.txt` both in Xcode and also in terminal. inside of Xcode this results in the output line displaying:

```
Enter driving time in hrs: command <input.txt
Enter driving speed in kph: 
Enter km per liter:
Your driving cost is nan NIS
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

While in terminal it does nothing.
I have also tried placing the input/output files inside of `DerivedData` but that has not helped...

Any advice would be a huge.

Answer (score 1):

What I think you should do:

If it was on Linux OS your I/O should be redirected by using something like that

> bash-4.1$ cat input.txt | yourbinary > output.txt

Perhaps things might not happen as you wish.
First whats the content of input.txt?
If it sounds like that :

```
2.3
100.00
```

Its better to read the file inside your program.
If you want something different, you may use linecommand parameters, they will look like that:

> bash-4.1$ ./command --speed=100.00 --kmperliter=12

You can also print from the inside of application to standard output with printf. If you do this the command line call will look like that:

> bash-4.1$ ./command --speed=100.00 --kmperliter=12 > output.txt

I hope it was useful